# How to get FineGrainedPasswordPolicy of the user without using LDAP and PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, ldap, password-policy

I want to know if some fined specific user has been subjected with some fine grained password policy. Which policy it is and other details. For this I know there are couple of ways for example ( PowerShell or LDAP ).

Due to certain reasons, I can't use LDAP and PowerShell. ( PowerShell probably would cause performance issues. )

Is there any other way exist in .NET library?

Comment: "I can't use LDAP" - can you use something that then uses LDAP on your behalf? LDAP is the primary directory interface, so saying you can't use LDAP but want to query the directory is a bit like saying you want to drive a car without sitting in the driver's seat...

Comment: Windows contains a database with the info and you need to query the database.  See : https://www.codemag.com/article/1312041/Using-Active-Directory-in-.NET?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article which provides some details on how the FGPP are configured against users, and the msDS-PSOApplied and msDS-ResultantPSO attributes of the user objects are used to define which FGP policy have been assigned.

https://nettools.net/how-to-display-which-fine-grain-password-policy-is-applied/